# Why cant .java files be shown correctly in IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After I move modules gRPC-client-introduction and gRPC-java-server into the directory gRPC-java-introduction as shown in the picture below. We can see that .java files have a red cycel in their left and bottom conner.

[image]

[image: I complete an entry level project of gRPC java. The project can be access at <https://github.com/cld378632668/gRPC-java-introduction> .]

The project is at https://github.com/cld378632668/gRPC-java-introduction/.

Comment: Did you add the appropriate folder as a source root?

Comment: The project structure seems weird. It looks like two separate Maven projects instead of a parent module with two sub-modules.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click `java` folder inside `src/main` directory-> Mark Directory as -> Sources root